# Rails allow user to set css settings

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

How can I allow the User to set font, font-size, and other site specific settings?

I suppose it results in loading specific CSS files when specific settings have been made. Maybe this could happen in the HTML header. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the best way to do this is to save the user specified styles as a file and store it on the server. Then, you could load the site with the default settings, and then use Javascript to load the alternate style sheet. The way to load a stylesheet using Javascript is something like so:

```
function setUserCSS(url) {
  var css = document.createElement("link");
  css.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
  css.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
  css.setAttribute("href", url);
}
```